# angular.extend/merge object with array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

If I have these objects:

```
var first = {arr: ["foo"]};
var second = {arr: ["bar"]};
```

and then do

```
angular.extend(first, second);
```

this will be the state:

```
first.arr[0] //"bar"
first.arr === second.arr;//true
```

I want the first part, but i don't want the arrays to be the same reference.

When i try

```
angular.merge(first,second);
```

then nothing happens to the `first.arr`

```
first.arr[0]; //"foo
```

What is the proper way to extend `first` with the properties of `second` including arrays, but not having the same references?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge both objects into new object:

```
angular.extend({}, first, second);
```

Then it should be what you want:

```
var first = {arr: ["foo"]};
var second = {arr: ["bar"]};

var result = angular.extend({}, first, second);

console.log(result.arr[0]); // bar
console.log(first.arr === second.arr); // false
```

Comment: The thing is `first` is a value service I use in various places so I need to update `first.arr`. Is `angular.copy` something I can use?